# Watch GH Actions workflow output in CLI?

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions

I am trying to execute a github workflow via the CLI, on a particular branch. The documentation for this is available here https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow_run

Is it possible to somehow get the same kind of logs you get with the browser UI in the terminal? I would like to programmatically interact with it.

If its possible with their rest api, then that is even better.
https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#create-a-workflow-dispatch-event As per the docs, it just returns a `Status: 204 No Content`.

Comment: I'm not sure about interacting with the action, so I won't post as a full answer for now, but you can use `gh run watch {id}`, as outlined in an official [blog post](https://github.blog/2021-04-15-work-with-github-actions-in-your-terminal-with-github-cli/), to get a printout in the terminal that automatically refreshes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to do trigger a workflow remotely using the Github API with the dispatch_event API you mentioned.

The **Github CLI** have various command for workflow (to `run`, `list`, `view`, `enable` ou `disable`). You can find more information on the [official documentation](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_workflow)

---

To get the logs from the Github CLI, [as explained here](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/using-workflow-run-logs#viewing-logs-with-github-cli), you can use commands such as:

```sh
gh run view run-id --log
```

*Note that if you don't specify run-id, GitHub CLI returns an interactive menu for you to choose a recent run, and then returns another interactive menu for you to choose a job from the run.*

You can also use the `--job` flag to specify a job ID. Replace `job-id` with the ID of the job that you want to view logs for.

```sh
gh run view --job job-id --log
```

You can use `grep` to search the log. For example, this command will return all log entries that contain the word error.

```sh
gh run view --job job-id --log | grep error
```

To filter the logs for any failed steps, use `--log-failed` instead of `--log`.

```sh
gh run view --job job-id --log-failed
```

Note that you can get a [workflow run id from the Github API as well](https://docs.github.com/en/rest/reference/actions#workflow-runs).

---

Therefore, as you should already have the `job_id` from the workflow file, it could be possible to start a workflow with a `dispatch_event` through the API, then get the workflow `run_id` from the workflow runs list API as well, and use the **Github CLI** command(s) in loop to get the logs.

It's not pretty, but it should work gathering all those steps in a script as a workaround.

Comment: But this will only allow me to trigger the workflow. Which is already possible via both the cli and the api. What I want is the output of the workflow, in the cli.

Comment: Ok, I've updated the answer. You can actually use the Github CLI for that too, if you know the workflow `run_id`. Which you can get from the API.

Comment: Yes but that wont be in sync with the progress of the workflow

Comment: plus any invocation of the workflow (either via the cli or the rest api doesnt return the job id)

Comment: Don't you already have the `job_id` from the workflow file? I understand it could be possible to start a workflow with a `dispatch_event` through the API, then get the  workflow `run_id` from the workflow runs list API as well, and use the `Github CLI` command(s) in loop to get the logs (it's not pretty, but it should work gathering all those steps in a script).

Comment: the problem is with run_id, if i run parallel workflows (on multiple branches) how would I get the run_id for a particular branch? Also I dont really see a neat way of getting the finished state of the workflow apart from hitting the api repeatedly

Comment: You would get the full log from the Github CLI, the API would be used only to get the workflow parameters. Moreover, regarding multiple workflows, you can get their  name and ref branch at the same time you get the run_id as they are returned by the Github API.